# $f(x)$ is a polynomial satisfying following conditions

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, quadratics

The second degree polynomial $f(x)$ satisfying $$f(0)=0, f(1)=1, f'(x)>0,  \forall x\in (0,1)$$ then show that $$f(x)= ax + (1-a)x^2 , a\in (0,2)$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Let $f(x)=bx^{2}+ax+c$. Since $f(0)=0$, so $c=0$ which says $f(x)=bx^{2}+ax$. Now $f(1)=1$ gives $a+b=1$ and so $b=1-a$. Thus your $f(x)=ax^{2}+(1-a)x$

Comment: This is a full answer. Why did you write it as a comment?

Comment: It's not quite a full answer, @John, as it doesn't grapple with $a\in(0,2)$. But OP can probably handle that much.